# Getting error when clicked on preview for lightning

Tags: managed-package, lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, url

I am working with lightning. This is first time I am trying it out. 
I have create a app, apex controller and js controller. I am just trying to get some information form my accounts and want to display it. But I when I try to check the preview the page I am getting error that

> URL No Longer Exists

Manage Package name in : focDMO1

My URL looks like this:
https://ap2.lightning.force.com/focDMO1/NewLight.app

App

```
 <aura:application controller="focDMO1.AccountComponentController">
     <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
     <aura:attribute name="accLst" type="focDMO1.Account[]"/>
 </aura:application>
```

newLightcontroller.js

```
({
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    helper.getAccountInfo(component);
}
})
```

apex controller

```
/*Light new  */
public class AccountComponentController {
   @AuraEnabled
   public static List<Account> getAccountInfo() {
       return [SELECT BillingState From Account Limit 20] ;
   }
}
```

newLighthelper.js

```
({
getAccountInfo : function(component) {
    var action = component.get("c.getAccountInfo");
    var that = this;
    action.setCallback(this,function(a) {
        component.set("v.accList",a.getReturnValue());
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action); 
},
})
```

Please help me out what is getting wrong in this.

Comment: do you have the helper function defined ?

Comment: @VamsiKrishna I have updated my question, please check.

Comment: u r missing the component parameter in the helper function.

Comment: @VamsiKrishna yes but after adding parameter component to the helper function getting the same issue.

Comment: @VamsiKrishna I am trying to get preview from developer console. Do I need to use Lightning app Builder with this. Do you think I am missing out anything. Anything which I need to update in profile.

Comment: Are you iterating through the list in your app using aura:iteration?

Comment: yes @DianaWidjajaMyerscough, but not getting error which is related to list exception or any problem with view of VF page, I am getting error that URL No Longer Exists.

Comment: https://ap2.lightning.force.com/one/one.app Please try this.. its the standard url for lightning application you've created.

Answer (score 0):

From **Lightning Components Developer Guide**;
"*Mark your resources with access="global" to make the resource usable outside of your own org; for example, if you want the resource to be usable in an installed package or by a Lightning App Builder user or a Community Builder user in another org.*"

So, please add GLOBAL access modifier to your app like; 
**aura:application access="GLOBAL" controller="focDMO1.AccountComponentController"**